# ASP.NET MVC Detecting Events (Clicks, Dropdown Changes, Checkbox Checks)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, razor

I have an Image Model that contains two booleans for IsMain and IsFeatured. I have a dropdown list that contains a ProjectId value for each option. What I want to do is when a selection is made from the dropdown, it hits the database to check the Images associated with that Project and verifies whether any of them already have IsMain or IsFeatured set to true. If so, it would disable those checkboxes. How would I do this not having to using any JavaScript?

Comment: short answer, without javascript, you'll have to reload your view (postback if you will) so the form is rendered according to the changes.

Comment: ..and you can't bind postback to dropdown change event, you are  limited to submit buttons or links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should realize that your C# code is run on the server, while JavaScript code is run on the client (in the browser). Once you have served the page to the user's browser, you have no server-side control over it.

So, if you don't want to use JavaScript at all, you are facing the following limitations:

- Your page is STATIC, you CAN NOT modify the page contents once it is served to the client.
- The only way you can interact with the user's input is via submit button click.

As you see, there is no way to accomplish what you want without JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I worked with WebForms a while ago and for some reason thought it was possible to do so using that in CodeBehind pages. But when I thought about it I was thinking of what you explained and was thinking it probably wasn't possible without JS.

Comment: Yes, WebForms were generating their own JavaScript under the hood, that's why something like that seemed possible with no manual JavaScript coding